# How to output pair of a reversed list at each iteration

Tags: python

How can I output pair of a reversed list at each iteration. For example, if `my_list=[11,22,33,44,55]`, I want to output (55,44) at the first iteration and (44,33) at the second iteration, and so on. I cannot think of anything other than the following way but it is not working :(

```
my_list = [11,22,33,44,55]
  for i in reversed(my_list):
     print (i, i+1)
```

Appreciate any hint.

Answer (score 3):

The [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) can be helpful here:

```
from itertools import tee, izip
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)
```

<sup>Note that on python3.x, you don't need `izip` -- you can just use `zip`</sup>

Now your loop is just:

```
for pair in pairwise(reversed(my_list)):
    print(pair)
```

---

Of course, we also don't *need* itertools here:

```
a = reversed(my_list)
b = reversed(my_list)
next(b, None)
for pair in zip(a, b):
    print(pair)
```

This lets you avoid worrying about python2.x/python3.x compatibility issues (because it'll work on python2.6+), but you don't get the nice re-useable (and easier to read) pairwise function.

Answer (score 2):

Given:

```
>>> my_list=[11,22,33,44,55]
```

You can do:

```
>>> zip(my_list[1:], my_list)[::-1]
[(55, 44), (44, 33), (33, 22), (22, 11)]
```

Or,

```
>>> reversed(zip(my_list[1:], my_list))
```

if you prefer.

Or, from comments (if you want Python 3 and 2 compatibility):

```
>>> zip(my_list[::-1], my_list[-2::-1])
```

Comment: In Python 3, `zip` returns an iterator, which you can't slice or pass it to `reversed`. You could do `zip(my_list[::-1], mylist[-2::-1])` though.

Comment: @Blckknght: Good call. Hopefully soon Python 3 will be the assumed default and Python 2 the call out exception...

Answer (score 0):

In your loop i is an element of the list not an index so incrementing it is not a good idea.

You can use nice pythonic way as mgilson gave or you can use a simple C-style loops to achieve this:

```
>>> my_list = [11,22,33,44,55]
>>> for i in xrange(len(my_list) - 1):
...    print my_list[len(my_list) - 1 - i], my_list[len(my_list) - 1 - i - 1]
... 
55 44
44 33
33 22
22 11
```